# How to make all cookies (even non-JSESSIONID cookies) be "http-only"?

Tags: java, security, cookies, https, wildfly

I can set our custom cookies in Java to be "secure" using myCookie.setSecure(true). However, there's no method for setting cookies to be HttpOnly. A customer has requested that all our cookies, not just JSESSIONID, be Secure AND HttpOnly.

We are using a WildFly server and Java to create these custom cookies.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was just an issue with Intellij saying the method didn't exist. I rebuilt manually and didn't get an error even with the setHttpOnly(true) method in there.

Answer (score 0):

The `setHttpOnly` method is available since servlet 3.0. Alternatively you can use methods of `javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie` that set `HttpOnly` to true.